# Onion juice and hair regrowth

Tags: hair, home-remedies, hairloss

I have read that onion juice is good to increase hair growth.

- Is onion juice really good for hair regrowth?
- I've heard/seen on the internet that Onion juice is good for this, is it worth a try ?
- Should I use a blender or just a grater to grind it?
- Should I add other ingredients like olive oil, honey, or lemon juice?

Comment: Your question is too broad in its current state, please reduce it to a single question per post.

Comment: @Narusan No it is not, it's all about Onion juice for hair loss, if it is good or not. If it is good, how that should be done. Do you have any suggestion for that ?

Comment: Two suggestions to improve this question: 1. Personal questions are considered off-topic, and although you are not explicitly requesting any, the paragraph about your baldness is unnecessary information and could be removed. 2. It would be great to ask another question about coffee and the effects of onion and coffee "therapy" together.

Answer (score 4):

Every single website that suggests onion juice is good for hair regrowth doesn't have credible sources. I went through a lot and all of them are full of mumbo jumbo and charlatans.

However, this onion madness seems to have some.. I repeat some... scientific basis and maybe that's where it all started.

**There is an actual research paper on the matter:**

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12126069

**The problem** though is that it was a very small study. Only 38 patients. They divided them in 2 groups and gave onion juice to one and plain **tap water** to the other. They noticed hair regrowth on the first group... but also on the second group!!!

**Does that mean onion juice is good for hair regrowth?** - Maybe, but the study is too small to prove anything.

**Does that mean water is good for hair regrowth?** - uh... I don't know, wouldn't there be a lot less bald people walking around?

Comment: +1 Nice research! Great to point out inconsistencies within the study.

Comment: Thank you! And sorry for the outburst. Must be the soft drinks I had earlier ;)